# Google Maps FragmentActivity error

Tags: android

I have an app using the google maps api, but I had to reinstall windows and now when I imported my project into eclipse I throws me multiple errors. However, all of them may be derived from one error.

I added Google Play Services as a library project following [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro).

Then I imported the sample project to eclipse but in the RetainMapActivity it throws an error on the `public class RetainMapActivity extends FragmentActivity` line:
*FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type*

And on the `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`:
*The import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity cannot be resolved*

There is no lib folder in the sample app but the docs didn't tell to add it.

The possible source of error in my app is in the xml containing the fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  map:cameraZoom="14"
  map:mapType="normal"
  android:layout_weight="2"
/>


Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'mapType' in package 
     'com.myapp'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in package 
     'com.myapp'
```

I have the android-support-v4.jar in the libs folder as well is in Properties/Java Build Path but in Properties/Android I marks the google-play-services_lib with a red X. I tried cleaning as well. And like I said, everything has worked earlier, before I formatted the hard drive.

Comment: the red x means a broken link you have not added google play service lib properly

Answer (score 0):

Android sucks again. Instead of File_Import I had to import the library as File_New_Other_Android Project from Existing Code.